# springboot zipkin and eureka server not working

Tags: spring-boot, microservices, netflix-eureka, zipkin

I am trying to build a springboot microservice application and i have service called eureka server which require zipkin to trace the logs.However when i add the dependencies with the latest,it gives the following error.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not find class [org.springframework.cloud.client.loadbalancer.LoadBalancerEagerLoadProperties]
    at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.resolveClassName(ClassUtils.java:333) ~[spring-core-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.core.annotation.TypeMappedAnnotation.adapt(TypeMappedAnnotation.java:465) ~[spring-core-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.core.annotation.TypeMappedAnnotation.getValue(TypeMappedAnnotation.java:390) ~[spring-core-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.core.annotation.TypeMappedAnnotation.asMap(TypeMappedAnnotation.java:278) ~[spring-core-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.core.annotation.AbstractMergedAnnotation.asAnnotationAttributes(AbstractMergedAnnotation.java:193) ~[spring-core-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.core.type.AnnotatedTypeMetadata.getAnnotationAttributes(AnnotatedTypeMetadata.java:106) ~[spring-core-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.core.type.AnnotatedTypeMetadata.getAnnotationAttributes(AnnotatedTypeMetadata.java:81) ~[spring-core-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigUtils.attributesFor(AnnotationConfigUtils.java:301) ~[spring-context-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
```

My pom:

```
 <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
        <spring.boot.dependencies.version>3.0.1</spring.boot.dependencies.version>
        <spring.cloud-version>2020.0.3</spring.cloud-version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.cloud/spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-server -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-server</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-sleuth</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-sleuth-zipkin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.6</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Properties.application:

```
spring.application.name=eureka-server
server.port=8761
eureka.client.fetch-registry=false
eureka.client.register-with-eureka=false
log.level.root=debug
spring.zipkin.base-url=http://localhost:9411
```

I search for the error and find there may be the problem on the version difference in one spring.cloud class and cause the error, however, when i use earlier version eureka dependencies, it cannot show the eureka homepage when browsing http://localhost:8761/.Neither the use of dependency
management works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see source 1.7 in your pom which is not supported anymore
[![jdk7 support dates][1]][1]
[check](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Release_table) for more details, If you open https://start.spring.io/ and add eureka server it generates pom below which uses java 17

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.3</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
  </parent>
  <groupId>com.example</groupId>
  <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>demo</name>
  <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
  <properties>
    <java.version>17</java.version>
    <spring-cloud.version>2022.0.1</spring-cloud.version>
  </properties>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-server</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>netflix-candidates</id>
      <name>Netflix Candidates</name>
      <url>https://artifactory-oss.prod.netflix.net/artifactory/maven-oss-candidates</url>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
      </snapshots>
    </repository>
  </repositories>

</project>
```

if you need to go below 17 you can use spring boot 2.7 which generates pom below

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.9</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
  </parent>
  <groupId>com.example</groupId>
  <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>demo</name>
  <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
  <properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <spring-cloud.version>2021.0.5</spring-cloud.version>
  </properties>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-server</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

</project>
```

please use https://start.spring.io/ when creating a project.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yBlne.png